# Questions about measurable mapping and product sigma algebra

Tags: measure-theory

1. Suppose there are three measurable spaces
   $(\Omega, \mathbb{F})$, $(S_i,
       \mathbb{S}_i), i=1,2$, and two
   measurable mappings $f_i: \Omega
       \rightarrow S_i, i=1,2$. Is the 
   mapping $f$ defined as
   $f(\omega):=(f_1(\omega),
       f_2(\omega))$ a measurable mapping
   from $(\Omega, \mathbb{F})$ to
   $(\prod_{i=1}^2 S_i, \prod_{i=1}^2
       \mathbb{S}_i)$, where $\prod_{i=1}^2
       \mathbb{S}_i$ is the product sigma
   algebra of $\mathbb{S}_i, i=1,2$?
2. Suppose there are four measurable spaces
   $(\Omega_i, \mathbb{F}_i), i=1,2$,
   $(S_i, \mathbb{S}_i), i=1,2$, and
   two measurable mappings $f_i:
       \Omega_i \rightarrow S_i, i=1,2$. Is
   the mapping $f$ defined as
   $f(\omega_1,
       \omega_2):=(f_1(\omega_1),
       f_2(\omega_2))$ a measurable mapping
   from $(\prod_{i=1}^2 \Omega_i,
       \prod_{i=1}^2 \mathbb{F}_i)$ to
   $(\prod_{i=1}^2 S_i, \prod_{i=1}^2
       \mathbb{S}_i)$?
3. In Part 1 and Part 2, conversely, if
   $f$ is a measurable mapping, will
   $f_i, i=1,2$ be measurable mappings?
4. Can the statements in Part 1,2 and
   3 be generalized to any
   collection of $(S_i, \mathbb{S}_i) i
       \in I$ and $(\Omega_i, \mathbb{F}_i)
       i \in I$?

Thanks and regards! Are there some websites or books that address these questions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. The product $\sigma$-algebra on $S_1\times S_2$ is generated by sets of the form $A\times B$, with $A\in \mathbb{S}_1$ and $B\in\mathbb{S}_2$. The function $f$ is measurable if and only if the inverse image of a measurable set is measurable, and it suffices to check that the inverse image of a measurable set in a specific generating set for the $\sigma$-algebra is measurable. So it suffices to see if $f^{-1}(A\times B)$, with $A$ and $B$ as above, is measurable.

   If $x\in f^{-1}(A\times B)$, then $f(x)\in A\times B$, so $f_1(x)\in A$ and $f_2(x)\in B$. Thus, $x\in f_1^{-1}(A)\cap f_2^{-1}(B)$. Conversely, if $x\in f_1^{-1}(A)\cap f_2^{-1}(B)$, then $f(x)\in A\times B$. So $f^{-1}(A\times B) = f_1^{-1}(A)\cap f_2^{-1}(B)$. Is this set in $\mathbb{F}$?
2. Same idea: what is $f^{-1}(A\times B)$? $(x,y)\in f^{-1}(A\times B)$ if and only if $x\in f_1^{-1}(A)$ and $y\in f_2^{-1}(B)$, so $f^{-1}(A\times B) = f_1^{-1}(A)\times f_2^{-1}(B)$. Is this set in the product $\sigma$-algebra $\mathbb{F}_1\times\mathbb{F}_2$?
3. Are the projection maps $\pi_i\colon (S_1\times S_2,\,\mathbb{S}_1\times\mathbb{S}_2)$ measurable? Is the composition of measurable functions measurable? What are $\pi_i\circ f$?

I'll leave 4 to you.

Comment: Thanks! In Part 4: (1) for questions similar to Part 1, if your proof in Part 1 can still apply here, since measurability of subsets is preserved only under countable intersection of measurable sets, if the collection of component sets are uncountable, then $f$ may not be measurable? (2) for questions similar to Part 2, if your proof in Part 2 can still apply here, I would like to ask when $I$ is infinite, $\forall A_i \in \mathbb{S}_i$, is $\prod_{i \in I} A_i$ still measurable wrt the product $\sigma$-algebra? If yes, then is the answer here also yes?

Comment: (3) for questions in Part 4 similar to Part 3, I guess your proof in Part 3 can still apply, and therefore the answer is the statements in Part 3 can be generalized to any collection of measurable spaces?

Comment: @Tim: In (1), notice that the sigma algebra, even in the infinite case, is generated by products in which only **finitely many** components are not the entire space. So you only need to worry about *finitely many* sets, not even countably many. This is not the "box" $\sigma$-algebra, but the product $\sigma$-algebra. Do it carefully. For (2), not necesarily. Again: the product sigma algebra is not the "box" sigma algebra. It is generated by sets of the form $\prod A_i$ where $A_i=\Omega_i$ for all but finitely many $i$. So, you have to be careful there. That is: be careful, and try it.